# How do I make a single page use ssl in Drupal 7?

Tags: webforms, ssl

I have a form I created with Webform, and I need it to be secure.  I don't need a login for everyone, only SSL for that one page.  Is that possible?  How do I use https:// for that one page?

Comment: Why only in that page not in the entire website?

Comment: I thought it didn't need it and that it would make it slow.  It can be the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Secure Pages module](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages). The module enables you to:

*A small process which will redirect the required pages to a SSL version of the page.*

To make use of it, take into account though that your webserver / webhost will need to support SSL and it should be configured for your site.